# Send Email using VBA 'Function Run-time error 438'

Tags: ms-access, smtp, vba, runtime-error

I'm trying to send email using VBA code, the function is working and the email is sent, but the problem is when function end 'Run-time error 438 object doesn't support this property or method' appears

here is the code:

```
Public Function SendEmail(ItemName As String, Total_Qnty As Integer)

 Set iMsg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

 Set iConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")

 Set Flds = iConf.Fields

 ' send one copy with Google SMTP server (with autentication)

 schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/"

 Flds.Item(schema & "sendusing") = 2

 Flds.Item(schema & "smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

 Flds.Item(schema & "smtpserverport") = 465

 Flds.Item(schema & "smtpauthenticate") = 1

 Flds.Item(schema & "sendusername") = "example@gmail.com"

 Flds.Item(schema & "sendpassword") = "*****"

 Flds.Item(schema & "smtpusessl") = 1

 Flds.Update


 With iMsg

     .To = "example@hotmail.com"

     .From = "example@gmail.com"

     .Subject = "Mail from gmail"

     .HTMLBody = "The Stock Safty Level of Item: " & ItemName & " is DOWN, The total      quantity you have is: " & Total_Qnty & "!!"

     Set .Configuration = iConf

     .Send

 End With


 Set iMsg = Nothing

 Set iConf = Nothing

 Set Flds = Nothing


End Function
```

Pleased any ideas .. Thank you

Comment: You should tell us what line the error message takes you to.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's a binary compatibility issue between components.

Microsoft says "*Run Time Error 438 - Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method:
The most common cause of error 438 is not maintaining binary compatibility between successive versions of your components. Each COM interface has an associated GUID that is called an interface ID (IID). Each coclass has an associated GUID that is called class ID (CLSID). When you compile an ActiveX component in Visual Basic, the CLSIDs and IIDs are compiled into the component's type library.*"

In this link it's explained how to solve a similar problem:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?460591-RESOLVED-Runtime-error-438-Object-doesn-t-support-this-property-or-method

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of these:

```
Set iMsg = Nothing

Set iConf = Nothing

Set Flds = Nothing
```

`Flds` is a member of iConf which, currently, you have already disposed of.